# Can Blender use color id maps to texture the same object with different materials?

Tags: texturing

I have an object I want to texture with different materials. I'm using ZBrush to create the object and have a color ID map made.

Can this be imported into Blender for texturing or do I need to select the faces in Blender first and assign it a different material there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your geometry has a color attribute, you can assign different materials based on different attribute values in Blender.